# How to pass date to WebAPI from HTML5 input type = "date" using Angular?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to use HTML 5 Input type = "Date" control to call a .NET web API from Angular.

On my HTML Page I see date correctly format "dd/mm/yyyy" on the HTML Control. However when I retrieve this value in angular controller I am getting this in format "Sun Sep 11 00:00:00 GMT-0400(Eastern Daylight Time". I am confused on how to take this date and pass to Web API having date parameter in action method.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>This is to test dates being passed from Angular to WebAPI </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body ng-controller="myController">
    <input type="date" ng-model="HireDate" placeholder="Hire Date" /> 
    <br />
    <input type="button" value="Get Employees" ng-click="getEmployees(HireDate)" /> 
   <!--<div ng-repeat="empSingleRecord in employee">
       empSingleRecord.FirstName + ' ' + empSingleRecord.LastName
   </div>-->

 <!--Get Angular Script Refrence--> 
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="App/AngularDateModule.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

///

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

//Create Controller 
app.controller("myController" , function($scope){
    // $scope.HireDate 

    $scope.getEmployees = function (varHireDate) {
        alert(varHireDate);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the full javascrit `Date` object printed. If you really want to use `dd/MM/yyyy` format, you can use angular `$filter` to format it:

```
$filter('date')(varHireDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy')
```

You do not need to do that if you're just sending it to the API. ASP.NET should be able to convert it as it is to a `DateTime`.

Comment: One thing I do not understand is $filter returns an string. The output of $filter (string), I am passing to WebAPI Parameter (datetime) and it did not complaint and still worked.

Comment: Another followup question is - Is HTML5 Input type="date" is a good control to use with Angular? I just want to see what other people are using?

Comment: WebApi parameter are always string. ASP.Net parse them automatically. I can't talk about the HTML5 date controls as I haven't used them with angular yet.